# Volume bounded between sphere and three planes

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, spherical-coordinates, bounds-of-integration

I found a question in my homework that I have been trying to solve for days with minimal progress. We're given a sphere of form $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$ and three planes, $x=1,y=1,z=1$

The sphere in question:
[image]

We're asked to find the volume bounded above the planes and below the sphere using an integral. I tried using Cartesian coordinates, only to get a nonintegrable equation with way too many roots. I tried using polar coordinates, still too many roots. Finally I used spherical coordinates. I split the question into two parts. Since the area of the wedge will be symmetrical on either side I solved for the volume bounded by $y=1,z=1, x=y$, and the sphere. This way the boundary would exclude the x=0 plane. I defined the integral as follows $$\int_{\arccos(\sqrt{(14)/4)}}^{\pi/4}\int^{\arccos(\sqrt{(7)/3)}}_{\arccos(1/3)}\int^3_{1/\cos\theta \sin\phi}\sin\phi p^2dpd\phi d\theta$$
The arccos values come from computing $\phi$ and $\theta$ at the points of intersection between the sphere and planes. $\pi/4$ is the upper bound for $\theta$ because I cut the question in half to avoid the x=1 plane from messing with my boundaries. That way I can just double my answer.

I don't think this answer is right. It's impossible to solve without a computer or converting the arccos values into lower decimal places so they're computable by hand. My answer was in the ballpark of my estimate using a triangular prism but was clearly too high. If anyone knows a more reasonable way to compute the boundaries I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Integrating in spherical coordinates, doing the $\theta$ integral first would only be one integral, but the resulting inverse trig would require many integration by parts, if it was clean to do at all. Doing $\rho$ first as you have set up would require three integrals, which you have not done correctly since you only have one. Probably doing $\phi$ first would be the way to go, as even though you would need two integrals, the inverse trig and trig cancel in the first integral.

Comment: Given your order of integration, I have used the same order to show the correct set up, even though it means split integral.

Answer (score 2):

Set up is easier in cylindrical coordinates so I will start with that and then go to spherical coordinates.

At the intersection of the plane $z = 1$ and the sphere, $x^2 + y^2 = r^2 = 8$

At the intersection of $y = 1, z = 1$ and the sphere, $x = \sqrt{7}$

$ \displaystyle \tan\theta = \frac{y}{x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt7}$

For $ \displaystyle \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$, the lower bound of $r$ is defined by plane $y = 1 \implies r = \csc\theta$

So the integral is,

$ \displaystyle \int_{\arctan(1/\sqrt7)}^{\pi/4} \int_{\csc\theta}^{2\sqrt2} r (\sqrt{9-r^2} - 1) ~ dr ~ d\theta$

Using symmetry you can double the volume or write the other integral as,

$ \displaystyle \int_{\pi/4}^{\arctan(\sqrt7)} \int_{\sec\theta}^{2\sqrt2} r (\sqrt{9-r^2} - 1) ~ dr ~ d\theta$

---

Setting it up in spherical coordinates, I will go in the order $d\rho, d\phi, d\theta$.

I will set it up for $ \theta \leq \pi/4$ and we can multiply the volume by $2$.

$\displaystyle \int_{\arctan(1 / \sqrt7)}^{\pi/4} \int_{\arcsin((\csc\theta)/3)}^{\arctan(\csc\theta)} \int_{\csc\theta \csc\phi}^3 \rho^2 \sin\phi ~ d\rho ~d\phi ~d\theta ~ + $

$ \displaystyle \int_{\arctan(1 / \sqrt7)}^{\pi/4} \int_{\arctan(\csc\theta)}^{\arccos(1/3)} \int_{\sec\phi}^3 \rho^2 \sin\phi ~ d\rho~ d\phi ~d\theta $

A bit of explanation for the above set up -

We know the bounds of $\theta$ from the work in cylindrical coordinates. For bounds of $\phi$, note that when $\rho$ is bound below by $y = 1$, lower bound of $\phi$ comes from intersection of $y = 1$ and the sphere, which is $y = 1 = 3 \sin\theta \sin\phi$. The upper bound of $\phi$ comes from intersection of plane $ y = 1$ and $z = 1$. At $z = 1, \rho = \sec\phi$ so $y = 1 = \sec\phi \sin\phi \sin\theta \implies \phi = \arctan(\csc\theta)$.

Now when $\rho$ is bound below by $z = 1$, lower bound of $\phi$ comes from intersection of plane $ y = 1$ and $z = 1$. So, $\phi = \arctan(\csc\theta)$ as we obtained earlier. The upper bound of $\phi$ comes from intersection of plane $z = 1$ and the sphere. So, $z = 1 = 3 \cos\phi \implies \phi = \arccos(1/3)$

Comment: Thank you for the easier calculation method. It seems I made a couple mistakes when I originally attempted to solve this problem using cylindrical coordinates. Considering how complicated it is to calculate any of the integrals you'd need, and how far beyond the scope of my course they are, I'm guessing there's a simpler, geometric way to solve the problem, maybe by subtracting simpler integrals from each other.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from my comment we can see that the volume is bounded by four surfaces which we can convert to spherical coordinates

$$\begin{cases}x=1\\y=1\\z=1\\x^2+y^2+z^2=9\end{cases} \implies \begin{cases}\rho\sin\phi\cos\theta=1\\\rho\sin\phi\sin\theta=1\\\rho\cos\phi=1\\\rho=3\end{cases}$$

Using different orders of integration we have $\theta$ first

$$\int_{\sqrt{3}}^3\int_{\csc^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho\sqrt{8}}{3}\right)}^{\sec^{-1}(\rho)}\int_{\sec^{-1}(\rho\sin\phi)}^{\csc^{-1}(\rho\sin\phi)} \rho^2\sin\phi \:d\theta d\phi d\rho$$

$\phi$ first

$$\int_{\sqrt{3}}^3\int_{\sec^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho\sqrt{8}}{3}\right)}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{\csc^{-1}(\rho\cos\theta)}^{\sec^{-1}(\rho)}\rho^2\sin\phi\:d\phi d\theta d\rho + \int_{\sqrt{3}}^3\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\csc^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho\sqrt{8}}{3}\right)}\int_{\csc^{-1}(\rho\sin\theta)}^{\sec^{-1}(\rho)}\rho^2\sin\phi\:d\phi d\theta d\rho$$

and $\rho$ first would be quite the mess. The $\phi$ integral can be shortened with symmetry (do one integral and multiply the result by $2$). As a start

$$I =  2 \int_{\sqrt{3}}^3\int_{\sec^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho\sqrt{8}}{3}\right)}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{\csc^{-1}(\rho\cos\theta)}^{\sec^{-1}(\rho)}\rho^2\sin\phi\:d\phi d\theta d\rho = 2\int_{\sqrt{3}}^3\int_{\sec^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho\sqrt{8}}{3}\right)}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\rho\sqrt{\rho^2-\sec^2\theta} - \rho\: d\theta d\rho$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: If you don't mind sharing, how did you find the boundaries for $\phi$ in the first equation? I understand computing the boundary for $\theta$ but you lost me at the next boundary. The transition from the x=1 to y=1 plane as an upper (lower?) bound for $\phi$ is causing me trouble.

Comment: Your work is wrong. Take for example where you are going $d\theta$ first - lower bound of $\phi$ is incorrect. The bounds of $\theta$ is reversed. The correct integral would be $ \displaystyle \int_{\sqrt3}^3\int_{\csc^{-1}(\rho / \sqrt2)}^{\sec^{-1}(\rho)}\int_{\csc^{-1}(\rho\sin\phi)}^{\sec^{-1}(\rho\sin\phi)} \rho^2\sin\phi ~d\theta ~d\phi ~d\rho$